# Sparx Enterprise Architect to get the Tagged ´Value from otDiagram VB Script code

Tags: vbscript, enterprise-architect

I have a UML diagram and all the component has tagged values . I would like to retrieve the tagged value with the element name .  Something like this to get the tagged value that i have code but dont know how to start it for a diagram.

```
function TVGetElementTaggedValue( theElement, taggedValueName, defaultValue )
    TVGetElementTaggedValue = defaultValue

    if not theElement is nothing and Len(taggedValueName) > 0 then
        dim taggedValue as EA.TaggedValue
        set taggedValue = theElement.TaggedValues.GetByName( taggedValueName )

        if not taggedValue is nothing then
            TVGetElementTaggedValue = taggedValue.Value
        end if
    end if

end function
```

Comment: A diagram isn't an [`EA.Element` object](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/9.3/automation/element2.html)!

Comment: Would you like to get tagged values for the diagram objects?

Comment: ya thats correct its a uml diagram and in that i have my tagged values and would like to retrieve using vb Script.

Answer (score 1):

There are no tagged values on diagrams.

Comment: its a uml diagram and in that i have my tagged values and would like to retrieve using vb Script.

Comment: In the light of Ajay's self-answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/26628799/2626313 do you have anything to change/review/enhance in your answer?

Comment: @xmojmr No not really, whatever the code in the self answer is doing (it isn't really clear to me), it isn't doing anything with tagged values defined on a diagram.

Comment: @GeertBellekens for me its working actually i am using the same code .But please the type of the diagram . I mean the please use this:if (Repository.GetTreeSelectedItemType() = otDiagram) 
 
  ' Show the script output window
  Repository.EnsureOutputVisible "Script"

  dim theDiagram as EA.Diagram
  set theDiagram = Repository.GetTreeSelectedObject()then                                 then call the function: TVGetElementTaggedValue(element, "your taggedvaluename","","")

Answer (score 1):

Finally Here is the solution that i have and it worked finally:

1. first select the type like this: `Repository.GetTreeSelectedItemType() = otDiagram`
2. call a function and keep a variable to store the data like this:
   `Roles = TVGetElementTaggedValue(element, "Roles", "", "")`
3. here is the function:

---

```
Function TVGetElementTaggedValue( theElement, taggedValueName, defaultValueMissing, defaultValueEmpty )

    if not theElement is nothing and Len(taggedValueName) > 0 then      
        dim taggedValue as EA.TaggedValue
        set taggedValue = theElement.TaggedValues.GetByName( taggedValueName )

        if taggedValue is nothing then
            TVGetElementTaggedValue = defaultValueMissing
' Dump warning          
'Session.Output(theElement.Name & " " & taggedValueName & " TAG Missing")           
        else
            if taggedValue.Value = "" then
                TVGetElementTaggedValue = defaultValueEmpty     
' Dump warning          
'Session.Output(theElement.Name & " " & taggedValueName & " Value Missing")         
            else
                TVGetElementTaggedValue = taggedValue.Value
            end if
        end if
    end if

end function
```

4. final print:

---

```
Session.Output("Roles:   " + CStr(Roles))
```

Thank you for the help.